# How come Next.JS code runs on both the Server and the Client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In a Next.JS app, you see that the code for a component runs on both the Server and the Client.

So if you have the following code:

```
const Title = () => {
  console.log('--> Hello')

  return (<h1>Some title</h1>)
}
```

and you run this in a dev environment (`npm run dev`), you will see the `console.log` statement print to both the Server in the terminal as well as the Browser's console.

So firstly, what is happening here? How come all the code on the page gets run in both places on every page load?

Wouldn't Next.JS just sent a pre-transpiled HTML file to the Browser? How come that `console.log` statement is getting run in the Server even though we're not in `getServerSideProps` or something similar?

Now, this may be a core feature of React that I've overlooked, so please tell me if it's just that manifesting in Next.JS

Comment: If you aren't doing SSR, then it only happens in dev mode. Never in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wouldn't Next.JS just sent a pre-transpiled HTML file to the Browser?

Yes, this is correct. But to transpile it to html it first needs to run your app and render it with `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` method.

So it is not specifically Next.js feature, but just a React SSR thing, every similar framework would do the same thing.

Comment: Ok, but in Dev mode, how come when you refresh the page, it logs out to the Server terminal window? Is that because the Server is creating a fresh build on every page load? So then it runs `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` each time? Furthermore, if you ran this in production mode (`npm start`), then it obviously would not run on the Server, correct? Because Next is just sending the pre-transpiled HTML to the Browser. Right?

Comment: Yes, in dev mode it usually makes new build on every page load. In production everything depends on what mode your page is using, for example simple page without any data fetching would be rendered at build time once and after `npm start` it would be just served from file system. You can read more here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#two-forms-of-pre-rendering

Comment: @Ben Yeah you are right. This is same thing that causes prop mismatch during development. Yes, it is sending the HTML that is built when you ran `npm run build`, and won't run in production unless you are doing SSR. Also it will be executed twice on server (in development mode) if you have React Strict Mode enabled.

Comment: So I have a similar question as it relates to Apollo. Does the Apollo query run on the Server or in the Browser when being run in Prod mode? From your answers above, I can deduce that the call occurs in the Browser only when being run in Prod mode, correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289281/in-a-next-js-app-do-apollo-queries-get-run-from-the-browser-or-the-server

Comment: @Ben request occurs from browser (in both production and development) always unless you are using it inside `getServerSideProps` or alike. In development, it may be fetched on both the server and client, although that's something I feel I need to check out first. In your particular question, in production mode, the `useMutation` code will executed from browser. If you want to fetch it from server, do SSR. If you don't want to execute in server use dynamic imports or put your code inside `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Thank you both. Really appreciated!